# Как в mysql вывести данные за неделю?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Есть вопрос, как мне вывести данные за неделю, учитывая день недели. Если понедельник, то выводим данные за понедельник. Если среда, то за понедельник, вторник, среду.

Какой я использую запрос:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM ugc_users WHERE dateRegistration >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

НО, он не работает ) И если я правильно понимаю, то он просто будет выводить за 7 дней. Если суббота, то оно будет считывать до следующей субботы.

Данные сохранены в бд так - 2021-09-16 17:59:41

Как сделать правильный запрос ?

Comment: *Если сегодня среда, то выводить данные за среду,четверг,пятницу,субботу,воскресенье.* В будущем, что ли?

Comment: Ахаха, оговорился. Сейчас исправлю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> вывести данные за неделю, учитывая день недели. Если понедельник, то выводим данные за понедельник. Если среда, то за понедельник, вторник, среду.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(id) 
FROM ugc_users 
WHERE dateRegistration >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE) DAY
  AND dateRegistration < CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Comment: Ничего не возвращает ( Данные в бд сохранены так - 2021-09-16 17:59:41. Возможно, это стоит учитывать

Comment: @Daniil Если неверно сформулировать условие, нет смысла ожидать подходящего решения, верно? См. откорректированную версию.